# WM_MOUSEMOVE between WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP, although mouse not moved

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using a software which duplicates graphical objects by clicking on them. The software expects that i do not move the mouse while clicking, so there are no WM_MOUSEMOVE messages between WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP. Unfortunatly (as i see with Winspector Spy) newer versions of Windows 10 send WM_MOUSEMOVE with the same x,y Coordinates as the WM_LBUTTONDOWN, while the mouse is pressed although the cursor is not moved. The software fails to duplicate the objects.

As an experiment i use a tool ([nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) "nircmd sendmouse left click") to simulate a mouseclick. In this case WM_LBUTTONUP comes directly after WM_LBUTTOWNDOWN and the software functions correctly.

The problem started with Windows 180x or 190x and it appears an all my computers. I am just a user of the software not the developer. Can i configure Windows to work the old way?

Comment: may be it's better to rewrite soft? you can use local mouse hook instead

Comment: See [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343) and [Why do I get a spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE message whenever Resource Manager is running?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160616-00/?p=93685) on Raymond Chen's blog

Comment: Can you use [`WH_MOUSE_LL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse_ll) to block/swallow the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message which resides between `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider filing a bug report with the software developer.

If the software is no longer maintained, then you will probably have to write your own program which injects your own DLL into the target process and installs a [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) using [`SetWindowsHookA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) with the `idHook` function argument set to `WH_MOUSE`. This allows you to filter out the mouse window messages that you don't want, before control is passed to the target application's window procedure.

I am not sure whether it is possible for the target application to detect that it is being tampered with. Most commercial software has some form of [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)/copy protection which will cause the program to stop working, if it detects any form of tampering, such as DLL injection.

Comment: You used to be able to do it with [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event). It is deprecated now, maybe that's what the original software used? That page suggests using SendInput instead. If that's sufficient, then it's likely a whole lot easier than installing hooks.

Comment: @Lundin: Those functions will generate additional window messages. However, if I understand the question correctly, OP wants less messages to be generated, not more messages. Or are you suggesting to only provide simulated input instead of real input? I don't think that this is what OP is asking for.

Comment: `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is posted. `WH_CALLWNDPROC` is called when a message is sent.

Comment: i doubt that soft that's rely on mouse messages could have any value.

Comment: @IInspectable: Are you saying that `WH_CALLWNDPROC` only hooks sent messages and not posted messages? I am unable to find anything in the documentation which confirms this. However, I did change my answer anyway to use `WH_MOUSE` instead of `WH_CALLWNDPROC`, because the documentation for `WH_CALLWNDPROC` does not specify that it is possible to prevent the message from being delivered to the target window procedure, whereas the documentation for `WH_MOUSE` does. Also, in OP's case, it seems more meaningful to only hook mouse messages instead of all messages.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel last time i've use it `setwwindowshookex()` with `WH_MOUSE`  will hook mouse related driver stuff , not messages. It blocks events so it no go further , not `WM_..` stuff. He needs system wide hook then and it's not so easy. It should (must) be placed  to own dll

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: `"WH_MOUSE will hook mouse related driver stuff , not messages"` -- I disagree with this statement. The official documentation for `WH_MOUSE` states that it is used for hooking "messages" when `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` is called. It does not talk about "mouse related driver stuff" or anything like that. I've never actually tested it, therefore my answer is based only on the official documentation.

Comment: yeah it's `WH_MOUSE_LL`